# How can I have a dynamic $default_view?

Tags: view, controller, default

Something along the lines of:

```
JLoader::Register('MyComHelperConfig', JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/helpers/config.php');

class MyComController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    protected $default_view = MyComHelperConfig::getDefaultView();
}
```

I gather that this may involve writing method overrides over the base class. What would be the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set a class property to a dynamic value, such as a method call, during declaration like you're attempting. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

You would need to set it in your constructor.

```
JLoader::Register('MyComHelperConfig', JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/helpers/config.php');

class MyComController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    protected $default_view = NULL;

    public function __construct($properties)
    {
        $this->default_view = MyComHelperConfig::getDefaultView();

        parent::__construct($properties);
    }
}
```

FYI, setting the property to NULL explicitly is not required. I set it out of habit. You could leave it out:

```
    protected $default_view; // same as "protected $default_view = NULL;"
```

Comment: Oh 'parent'. I was wondering what the equivalent for 'base' was in php. Much appreciated! 
PS: Apologies for not using legal code. I am aware that objects can't be given dynamic values in global space. I was too bent on portraying what result I needed.

Comment: :) no worries! Welcome to PHP. Happy coding.